# Firebase Performance SDK not detected on Android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I have created a project on Firebase and added the Firebase performance SDK as below,

build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf'
}
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.4'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <meta-data
     android:name="firebase_performance_logcat_enabled"
     android:value="true" />

 <meta-data
     android:name="firebase_performance_collection_enabled"
     android:value="true" />
```

But still, it shows to add SDK,

Below are the logs from FirebasePerformance

```
D/FirebasePerformance: CollectionEnabled metadata key unknown or value not found in manifest.
D/FirebasePerformance: CollectionEnabled metadata key unknown or value not found in manifest.
D/FirebasePerformance: Creating a new Non Verbose Session: cb90e041768b41e1af4468b5f1a98360
D/FirebasePerformance: CollectionEnabled metadata key unknown or value not found in manifest.
D/FirebasePerformance: Creating a new Non Verbose Session: 14b444366e4844628a6441ac147cf4a5
D/FirebasePerformance: Transport is not initialized yet, trace metric: _as (duration: 662.1190ms) will be queued for to be dispatched later
```

Can anyone tell me what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added below lines to your project level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
// Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
google()  // Google's Maven repository
}
```

Also you have not defined version for your depedencies

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.11'
```

Comment: Yes it is added

Comment: You have not added versions to dependencies. check solution again.

Comment: That's not required when using bill of materials. And the logcat suggests that it's not a dependency issue.

Comment: I want to understand what this logs means?

Comment: Yes you are using BOM, its not required to set version explicitly. Just rebuild your project. Do not pay more attention to logcats. Just check your app is working fine as per your  requirements or not.

Comment: My app is working fine.I tried all the suggestion but it did not work

Comment: Then whats the issue, if app is working fine

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/disable-sdk?platform=android), it is enabled by default (initialized by `FirebaseApp`).

Check for `gradle.properties`, if not that may override it... since the error message makes little sense (no sense at all), maybe once try do delete all `build` directories and Gradle caches.

You can safely remove that part:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_performance_collection_enabled"
    android:value="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forgot to add google plugin

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'